# Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer' Angular8+

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am currently working with **ngx-extended-pdf-viewer** with Angular8+ to render a PDF, it doesn't work. And I keep getting the runtime error "Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'pdf-viewer'".

Does anyone know why this is?

Here is my HTML:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer 
                            [src]="pdfSrc" 
                            [useBrowserLocale]="true" 
                            [textLayer]="true"
                            [showHandToolButton]="true"
                            [height]="'100vh'">
                        </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my app.module.ts

```
...
import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule,
    ....

  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...


  ],
  providers: [
   ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-video-reader',
      templateUrl: './video-reader.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./video-reader.component.css'],
      providers: [NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule]

    })
    export class VideoReaderComponent implements OnInit {

      pdfSrc = "assets/example.pdf";  /* PDF*/


      constructor() { }

      ...

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.video = 'jYvkMv7LzCw';
        this.init();
      }

     ...

    }
```

my app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole `AppComponent`?

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: You need to add the `NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule` to the imports of every module where you are using the `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer`. Are the HTML and .ts files in a component, that is declared in the AppModule?

Comment: Yes, all the files are declared in the AppModule

Comment: I even added to my .ts : 
`import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule]

})`

Comment: Can you show the component class?

Comment: What is "my .ts"? Can you provide the whole template?

Comment: I added my ts to the post

Comment: Please post the whole `app.component.html` / `video-reader.component.html`. If you keep on posting breadcrumbs nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by:

```
> npm update 
> npm install
> npm audit fix --force
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `[(src)]="pdfSrc"`
It's a two-way binding attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but same problem!

Comment: this is different to what the documentation says. Also, doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Use src="pdfSrc"

It's works

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your contribution!  Unfortunately, the OP is asking for "binding" and this will not achieve that.  Please consider modifying this answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).